# Phonegap Web Server Configuration - Durandal App

Tags: ajax, apache, cordova, cors

I can't find any documentation on what type of internal server PhoneGap is running on mobile devices, whether it's Apache, IIS, or some other minified web server. I'd like to know what type of server it is and whether it can be configured to allow external communication to a server, which is rejecting the incoming requests because it doesn't have the CORS support added to it.

We have 3 options

```
 1) Add CORS support to allow AJAX from PhoneGap device to the web servers
 2) Configure the PhoneGap web server to act as a proxy
 3) Add a plugin, or write a plugin, which allows a native Android function call to allow communication to the web server
```

If you have any experience with these or advice on which way to go, your help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no internal server. PhoneGap/Cordova creates a base native application with the default view as a webview. A webview is a blank version of a web browser window. There is no web server component to PhoneGap.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply. So if I'd like to add CORS support to a server, would the device source address be localhost for communication coming from the application?

Comment: The source address would be something like `file://APP_PATH/index.js`. For API calls I use jQuery `ajax` methods and set various headers to allow for this. Here is the main code I use: https://github.com/dawsonloudon/Cordova-Starter/blob/master/www/js/api.js

Comment: Thanks! That'll help out a lot. Another question, I made an AJAX call within my PhoneGap application to a public JSON calls server which returns my IP address. Did this work because CORS support isn't needed on the server side because of the way PhoneGap is set up or did they whitelist every single source address on their web servers? Here is my function call: $.getJSON to www.telize.com/geoip?callback=?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but they probably have an open whitelist.